# QWebTemplateNotFound error after deleting the database

Tags: odoo-9

I deleted the database and trying to create another one, after entering the database manager homepage, and creating the database I got this internal server error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 252, in render
element = self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 174, in get_template
raise_qweb_exception(QWebTemplateNotFound, message="Loader could not find template %r" % name, template=origin_template)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 172, in get_template
document = qwebcontext.loader(name)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1072, in loader
return self.read_template(cr, uid, name, context=context)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 946, in read_template
view_id = self.get_view_id(cr, uid, xml_id, context=context)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 950, in get_view_id
return self.pool['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(cr, uid, xml_id, raise_if_not_found=True)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 991, in xmlid_to_res_id
return self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(cr, uid, xmlid, raise_if_not_found)[1]
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 983, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
return self.xmlid_lookup(cr, uid, xmlid)[1:3]
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/git/odoo9/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 973, in xmlid_lookup
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: web.login
```

and the odoo homepage cannot be loaded..

Comment: Take a pull from git branch and try to create another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem in my case was clearing all browser history. Still don't know why but it worked.